# How can I access a variable value in view from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got two controller-view pair. I load a view, from my A_Controller, with $data variable. In the new view(B_View) with a new controller(B_Controller) I can access that data, but I would like to use it in the view's controller (B_Controller) too. Is there anyway to access itt?

**A_Controller**

```
class A_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   public function index{
      $variable= "some_data";
      $data['variable'] = $variable
      $this->load->view('B_View', $data)
   }
}
```

**B_View**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <!-- I can access it here -->
      <h1><?php echo $variable;?><h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

**B_Controller**

```
class B_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   public function some_function{
      $new_variable = $variable; //but I can't access it here :( 
   }
}
```

Comment: Not an expert in CI but you could create an instance of B_Controller and then pass `$variable` as a method parameter to `some_function()` or you could send an ajax request to `B_controller`  from `B_view`.

Comment: use `class B_Controller extends A_Controller {`

Comment: make a property in contructor of Class A, then extent ClassA with ClassB... and get the the property value in CLASS B

Comment: @AME Don't  use inheritance just to get the value of a variable if these 2 controllers don't follow a parent child relationship. This would break your design.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I don't want to use unnecessary dependencies there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pass sensitive data like mobile number or something personal I don't accept using session to pass data across controller functions. If you have lot of variables and if they fetch data from a db it better to make a separate controller to load required data into a function. But keep in mind dont load any view in this function. Just load required data. If your data fetching function has lot of variables it may affect to your web site loading speed. However when you have a seperate function and a controller to load data then you can redirect to that controller in other functions and then access into the required variable.

```
 class B_Controller extends CI_Controller {

   public function some_function{
        redirect('/Data_Controller/data_function');
         $new_variable = $variable; 
     }
   }
```

Hope this make sense to you problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use **SESSIONS**

1. Enable sessions globally in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

2. In A_Controller, initialise your variable and store it in a session

```
class A_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   public function index{
      $variable= "some_data";
      $this->session->set_userdata(array('variable'=>$variable)); //store variable in a session
      $data['variable'] = $variable;
      $this->load->view('B_View', $data)
   }
}
```

3. In B_Controller, get the variable via the session

```
class B_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   public function some_function{
      $new_variable = $this->session->userdata('variable'); //get back variable from session
   }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use session, but my problem with it this is not that kind of user data what I want to use everywhere. It can be a solution but I was hoping there is an better one.

Comment: You can clear the session when you no longer need it.
```$this->session->unset_userdata('variable');```

Answer (score 1):

You can use codeigniter Session to pass data from one controller to another controller or redirect the controller with controller name and the method

```
   class B_Controller extends CI_Controller {

   public function some_function{
        redirect('/A_Controller/index');
         $new_variable = $variable; 
     }
   }
```

> Via session

First set the $variable into flash data

```
class A_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   public function index{
      $this->load->library('session');
      $variable= "some_data";
      $data['variable'] = $variable;

      $this->session->set_flashdata('variableName', $variable);

      $this->load->view('B_View', $data)

   }
}
```

Now fecth it in second controller

```
 class B_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   public function some_function{

      $new_variable = $this->session->flashdata('variableName');

      $new_variable = $variable;  
   }
}
```

Please note I have not tested this code but I think you may able to grab something via this.Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use session, but my problem with it this is not that kind of user data what I want to use everywhere. It can be a solution but I was hoping there is an better one. Actually I really don't like php, but at my work I have to refactor a webservices in Codeigniter, and now I'm really suffering with it. I talked about the problem with my colleague, and he said that it is not a really safety way. It is sensitive data, what I want to pass there back to the controller.

Comment: @AME just for a example tell me what type of data you wants to pass across the controllers

Comment: Personal data, for example personal number,

Comment: @AME So i think its better to use 1st choice in my answer

Comment: Can I simply call a function in html? Could you extend your exmaple code with the call in the view. So how do you call some_function in the view.

Comment: Wait. I guess it is not solve my problem. You know why? It's okay, if I use the first way, I can pass it in one function. But not in the right one. On the new view, I got a form, and on submit it call's a function. I want to use that data there, so with this way, It won't work.

Comment: @AME are you using whatsapp

Answer (score 1):

> Why dont you do `$data['variable'] = "SOME DATA"` in the controller you will be able to use it in the view like `<?= $variable; ?>` :)

Comment: I can already use it in the view, that problem is that I can't use it in the view's controller. Because the view have another controller.